# Check my DHCP lease?

Tags: networking, dhcp, dhclient

Is there a way to show my current (client) DHCP lease?

Or even better - retrieve all options/infos sent with `DHCPACK`?

Comment: `/var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases`?

Comment: @heemayl this file is empty in my case (Ubuntu 15.10), maybe because NetworkManager is acquiring dhcp lease (?)

Comment: `ipconfig getpacket <ifname>` or `ipconfig getv6packet <ifname>` on Mac OS X.

Comment: @heemayl, Nope. `No such file or directory`

Comment: @heemayl was correct for the directory. On Debian Stretch I found infos in "/var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.eth0.leases"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used `dhcpdump` when I was testing DHCP.  It will dump both sides of the DHCP transaction.  If you leave it running it will log the options passed.

You may want to restart your DHCP client to see the initial negotiation.  The renewal request should contain all the running configuration.

Answer (score 11):

I'm not aware of a way to query this information on the client. If you are on the server you can see information on the client leases in `/var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases`. From the client the only way i know is:

```
sudo grep dhclient /var/log/syslog
```

Which should give you something like:

```
May 20 18:34:38 [machine_name] dhclient: DHCPREQUEST on eth0 to [DHCP_SERVER_IP] port 67
May 20 18:34:38 [machine_name] dhclient: DHCPACK from [DHCP_SERVER_IP]
May 20 18:34:38 [machine_name] dhclient: bound to [client_dhcp_ip] -- renewal in 1517 seconds.
```

Answer (score 10):

With NetworkManager use `nmcli` to query the DHCP status for your active connection (assuming one) with

```
nmcli -f ipv4.method con show "`nmcli -t -f NAME connection `"
```

For full DHCP information use `-f DHCP4`. Adjust for ipv6 as necessary.

Comment: This prints the DHCP information for the currently active connection: `nmcli -f DHCP4 con show "$(nmcli -g NAME con show --active)"`

Comment: This is the only method that works on my computer so far.

Answer (score 8):

depending on your distro, it should be located in `/var/lib/dhcp` under `dhclient.{interface}.leases or /var/lib/dhclient.leases`. you can also specify the path of your dhclient.leases file by passing -lf  when starting dhclient.

Comment: @madeon it should be under `/var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.{interface}.leases e.g /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.eth0.leases`

Answer (score 7):

There is one other aspect to this answer to consider to show your DHCP lease time and other DHCP information in the offer.  If using Linux systemd-networkd, none of the options above work as they relate to network manager (the Linux solutions at least)

There is a similar question with answer explaining this at
[How do I check DHCP lease time in systemd-networkd?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/429529/how-do-i-check-dhcp-lease-time-in-systemd-networkd)

Quoting from that answer:

> Depending on the OS; Enabling debug isn't always necessary.
>
> systemd-networkd should store the lease info under
> `/run/systemd/netif/leases/`
>
> i.e.
>
> ```
> cat /run/systemd/netif/leases/2
> ```

Answer (score 4):

### Check Which Lease?!?!

If you thought this couldn't get anymore confused, you'd be wrong ;-)

I found this question unpicking my own DHCP issues on Ubuntu 22.04 **Desktop** edition, where I discovered that I actually had **TWO** leases!:

```
sudo cat /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases

sudo cat /var/lib/NetworkManager/internal-d6b936ad-d73f-4898-a826-edbb61d6155a-eth0.lease
```

*So which is the one being used...?*

### (2) DHCP Clients:

Unlike Ubuntu's LTS server flavour, their Desktop edition winds-in ***NetworkManager*** into the networking gears.

And [NetworkManager has its' own DHCP client](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NetworkManager#DHCP_client).

### Determine Default DHCP Client

So, there's (2) DHCP clients in this case, but ***which of these are actually being used?***

In Ubuntu Networking, there is a layer of abstraction called ***netplan*** which sets the default networking gears in the directive `renderer`.

A review of `/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml` reveals that *NetworkManager is controlling our networking*, NOT ***systemd-networkd***.

A review of NetworkManager's logging:

```
 journalctl -u NetworkManager.service | grep DHCP
```

reveals that NetworkManager is using its' own DHCP client:

```
NetworkManager[5117]: <info>  [1655970837.0088] dhcp-init: Using DHCP client 'internal'.
```

Thus, of our (2) leases, the one being used by the system is:

```
/var/lib/NetworkManager/internal-d6b936ad-d73f-4898-a826-edbb61d6155a-eth0.lease
```

Note the keyword in that log message is "***using***": even if a gazillion DHCP clients are shown in the logging as `enabled`, only the one specified as "***using***" is the active DHCP client.

Wow, this was a tangle; hope this saves others going down the same deep, dark rabbit hole...

Answer (score 2):

On current Debian you can find the information in `/var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.leases` which looks like this:

```
lease {
  interface "eth0";
  fixed-address 10.224.129.116;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option dhcp-lease-time 3600;
  option routers 10.224.129.1;
  option dhcp-message-type 5;
  option dhcp-server-identifier 10.224.129.1;
  option domain-name-servers 10.224.129.1;
  option dhcp-renewal-time 1800;
  option dhcp-rebinding-time 3150;
  option broadcast-address 10.224.129.255;
  option host-name "tk-otc-client";
  option domain-name "dd.otc";
  renew 4 2020/12/03 09:56:25;
  rebind 4 2020/12/03 10:26:09;
  expire 4 2020/12/03 10:33:39;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me what does the number 4 after renew mean ?

Comment: 4 means Thursday (0-6 -> Sunday-Saturday) as explained in https://linux.die.net/man/5/dhclient.conf .

Answer (score 0):

Know your Unix/Linux :-) There are more DHCP client programmes available.

One, fairly frequent option is to use dhclient. It is usually set to write full "PACK" answer decoded into a file. File is usually somewhere in /var.

Something like `find /var -name '*leases*'` can give you a hint. Mine is `/var/db/dhclient.leases.em2` (OpenBSD).

Or give some detail about SW you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I am using arch linux and `dhclient.leases` can be found inside `/var/lib/dhclient/`

so you can do `cat /var/lib/dhclient/dhclient.leases` to view leases.