# How do I check DHCP lease time in systemd-networkd?

Tags: arch-linux, dhcp, systemd-networkd

How do I find the DHCP lease time when I am using `systemd-networkd`?

My network is defined in `/etc/systemd/network/eth0.network`:

```
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
DHCP=yes
```

There are other question on this site asking for the same information but they weren't using `systemd-networkd` but `dhclient` or some other method.

I've tried looking in `journalctl` to no avail. I’m using ArchLinux.

Comment: Try `grep lease /var/log/syslog`.

Comment: @tomasz forgot to mention that I’m using ArchLinux which uses journald not syslog. I’ve updated the question

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Depending on the OS; Enabling debug isn't always necessary.

`systemd-networkd` should store the lease info under `/run/systemd/netif/leases/`

i.e.

`cat /run/systemd/netif/leases/2`

Comment: At least in my version, /run/systemd/netif/leases/ does NOT include the lease time. - which is the question.

Answer (score 6):

Per Lennart's [post here](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2017-May/038936.html), you have to change  `systemd-networkd` log level to `debug`.
If you wanted to have it on all the time you could use a drop-in unit:

```
mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service.d
cat << IN > /etc/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service.d/10-debug.conf
[Service]
Environment=SYSTEMD_LOG_LEVEL=debug
IN
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart systemd-networkd
```

Answer (score 5):

I can't find authoritative documentation for this, but I think networkd's DHCP client uses the received DHCP lease duration to set `valid_lft` and `preferred_lft` on the address in kernel, and thus the remaining lease duration is simply shown with `ip address show`:

```
$ ip -4 a s eth0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 192.168.2.7/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 59397sec preferred_lft 59397sec
```